# How does setting aspnet:RequestQueueLimitPerSession work in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, session, http2, aspnetcore-environment

**Background:** we ran into this inconvenient issue in our ASP.NET site where in one scenario the browser fired a huge number of request to the server, and since communicating over http/2 and utilizing concurrent request mechanism the ASP.NET request queue limit (*) was exceeded whereupon the requests get terminated and nasty 500 is returned from the server.

(*) yes, because reasons, that exists - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.6.2-4.7.1#throttle-concurrent-requests-per-session)

One way to handle this is of course with better lazy loading handling to prevent the huge number of requests being fired at once (this has been done for this specific scenario).

However, another way, and what we find as a more overall solution for making this session request queue limit cooperate better with concurrent requests, is to tweak this queue limit by bumping setting `aspnet:RequestQueueLimitPerSession`, as discussed in this thread [The request queue limit of the session is exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59938410/the-request-queue-limit-of-the-session-is-exceeded)

However, we are insecure on how this setting are operating with ASP.NET Core projects? We can’t seem to find any information whatsoever regarding this, or information regarding how this request queue limit is set to work with concurrent requests overall. Does anyone have experience and some information regarding this setting in ASP.NET Core?